# form bootstrap con grilla y php al inicio

Tags: php, bootstrap

acabo de iniciarme con PHP y Bootstrap ***(qué versión es recomendable de Bootstrap, 5 ?)*** y deseo hacer lo siguiente, para lo cual consulto:

Realizar un formulario que **muestre una grilla al cargar la pagina** y algunos inputs de datos no editables. Otros, editables. El PHP ya lo hice, es una consulta básica, pero no sé **cómo ejecutarlo cuando carga la página**.

Luego, lo que deseo es que cada vez que hago **click sobre una fila de la grilla, alguna de esas columnas, pasen su valor a los inputs no editables**. (todos string salvo una fecha)

Por último con un botón tipo submit, ejecutaré un **PHP para hacer update sobre tabla MYSQL** , cosa que a hice.

Les agradeceré si me pueden ayudar con esto, estoy abandonando flash

Muchísimas gracias !

Comment: Observaciones: El primer texto resaltado se basa en opiniones y puede que tu pegunta sea mal recibida. Por favor, añade lo que hayas intentado, lee más la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/) y mira algunos ejemplos, enserio que hay **MUCHÍSIMOS** en internet

Comment: sube tu codigo para que podamos entender la situación